# Cocoa - Remove All Chars Before and Including Substring from String

Tags: cocoa, search, nsstring

getting myself confused with NSString's various range methods and where and when they should be used.

I have a random string. Somewhere in the string it may (or may not) contain an identifier such as "Customer Name:" (the quotes will not be included.)

**Problem**: I need a new string where everything up to and *including* "Customer Name:" has been removed from the original string.

Any advice is appreciated.

Mac OS X 10.4 compatibility required, manual GC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@"Customer Name:"];
NSString *newStr = [str substringFromIndex:range.location + range.length];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Along with a check on the range result, that works great. Cheers.